# Get values in URL path string JS

Tags: javascript, url, substring

I need to fetch the "**NEED_THIS**' from the below URL as separate strings.

'https://something--something.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/**NEED_THIS/NEED_THIS**?inContextOfRef=1.eyJ0eXBlIjoic3RhbmRhcmRfX29iamVjdFBhZ2UiLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7Im9iamVjdEFwaU5hbWUiOiJTdXBwb3J0X1JlcXVlc3RfX2MiLCJhY3Rpb25OYW1lIjoibGlzdCJ9LCJzdGF0ZSI6eyJmaWx0ZXJOYW1lIjoiUmVjZW50In19&count=1'

Is there any easy way to fetch this?

I already used  *decodeURIComponent(window.location.href.split('?')[0]);* to get upto
https://something--something.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/NEED_THIS/NEED_THIS

Answer (score 0):

First things first,

```
window.location.protocol = “https:”
window.location.host = “something--something.lightning.force.com”
window.location.pathname = “/lightning/o/NEED_THIS/NEED_THIS”
window.location.search = “?inContextOfRef=1.eyJ0eXBlIjoic3RhbmRhcmRfX29iamVjdFBhZ2UiLCJhdHRyaWJ1dGVzIjp7Im9iamVjdEFwaU5hbWUiOiJTdXBwb3J0X1JlcXVlc3RfX2MiLCJhY3Rpb25OYW1lIjoibGlzdCJ9LCJzdGF0ZSI6eyJmaWx0ZXJOYW1lIjoiUmVjZW50In19&count=1”
```

to break the pathname up, you can split it using:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
```

Then access the different parts by the parts of the array, like

```
var secondLevelLocationPartOne = pathArray[2];
var secondLevelLocationPartTwo = pathArray[3];
```

Then you can use it whereever you need it. for reference, click this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/)